# Laravel 4.2, Whoops and blank error pages with right <title> and app/storage writable

Tags: php, laravel

Since one of the last updates Whoops doesn't show me an exception-page with stack-trace anymore. It's just a blank page where the title (-tag) is set to "Whoops! There was an error." but other than that the site is blank.

I don't know why this is happening. I've tried about every solution in the internet. My app/storage permissions are set and working, because I still get the log of the exception there!

But manually opening the log and digging through it is kind of tedious and tiresome.

Any ideas why this could be happening SUDDENLY?

Oh, I'm running Nginx and php fpm with php 5.5 (latest stable version) but I always did that, so nothing has changed there.

I'd highly appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance.

edit: app/config/app.php debug is set to true of course (although I'm using another environment and it's set there as well. I tried to disable the environment etc.)

A *FRESH* installation of L4.2 brings exactly the same results. If I go to an undefinied Route I should get an exception like "Could not find Route" (or something like that, an Exception thrown by Symfony Routing component). Anyway, I don't get an exception on screen. It is written into the log-file, but the html of the page is like:

```
<html>
<title>Whoops!....</title>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you have in the view in question?

Comment: Is debug turned on? app/config/app.php

Comment: Does the log say something about the error?

Comment: @msturdy: The view in question can be anything. I tried reinstalling today and get it on the hello.php (vanilla laravel 4.2 apart from that!)

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro: It is and it always was. Although I'm using another environment here I enabled it in all, just for testing. Same result ;)

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: Depends on the exception of course. But for me FRESH INSTALLED L4.2 App: If I got to an unspecified route like: mydomain.tld/this/is/not/a/valid/route it puts the whole stack-trace into the log. (Like it should) Like "couldn't find the specified Route" (normal behaviour), but that's just in the Log, never on screen. The view is just white/blank, with the title set, but no content.

Comment: A recent laravel update changed the config structure so that debug is off by default but is enabled in the "local" environment, which only works if you set up your hostname to point to "local".

Comment: @Artsemis: As I said, this is not the problem here, the debug-value is set TRUE ;) (in EVERY environment now, still no change!) Also, the <title> gets set accordingly, so the problem should be another one :) Still, thanks for trying to help! will try if the <title> is set because of browser-cache...

Comment: @Nalrakesh: I was referring to the new installations -- which is why I just commented and didn't post as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Artsemis: Ya, thanks. Still, I did change that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this....

1. Go to

vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Resources/views/layout.html.php file.

2. add die() at last to this file

I hope this will work in your case...